# Solve for all $x,y\in N$ and $x^3-3^y = 2015$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Question:

> Solve for all $x,y\in N$ and $x^3-3^y = 2015$

So far I have tried $\mod(7)$ and $\mod(8)$ but I am not sure if I am in the right path or not I will be happy if someone can toss me a hint.

Comment: You can put a bound on $x$ and $y$, and reduce the problem to a finite search.

Comment: Checking $\!\!\!\mod 2$ and $\!\!\!\mod 3$, we see that $x$ is even and $x\equiv 2\!\!\!\mod 3$, i.e. $x\equiv 2\!\!\!\mod 6$. Also, $x\ge\sqrt[3]{2016}$, so $x\ge 14$. For example, $x=14$ and $y=6$ works.

Comment: @Helixglitch Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E3-3%5Ey%3D2015%24&p=1), I found the somewhat related [On natural solutions of the equation $y^{3}-3^{x}=100$](/q/43326) (plus the AoPS threads [Interesting Number Theory Problem](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2531824p21527184) and [Integer solutions](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2171553p16172868) which deal with that same equation). You may find the approaches used in the answers to the Math SE question to be of use with your RHS of $2015$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Metin's idea of "reject solution of too large" and
someone's idea of mod $13$ -> $3\mid m$, I reach a solution.

Consider mod $13$, then

$3^y\equiv1,3,9 \pmod {13}$

$x^3\equiv1,5,8,12 \pmod {13}$

Thus, $3^y\equiv1 \pmod {13}, x^3\equiv1 \pmod {13}, 3\mid y$

Let $y=3z, k=3^z$, so $x>k>0$

Then $x^3-3^y = x^3-(3^z)^3 = x^3-k^3 = (x-k)(x^2+xk+k^2) = 2015 $

$x^2+xk+k^2$ is factor of $2015$ and thus bounded above, we can have $x<45$. Then the rest is check and reject by computer. (By hand is tough)

Furthermore, consider $x^3-27^z=2015$ with mod $7$, we have $7\mid x$. (Consider all outcomes as above). With $x\equiv2 \pmod{6}$ by Alexander. We can reject all $x<45$ except $14$.

Comment: Nice!${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: I saw right where this was going after reading your "$3|y$". Then $3^y$ is a perfect cube along with $x^3$. Very nice!

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: The proof has a fatal flaw as pointed out in the comments.

We will show that the solutions cannot be infinitely large and reduce the infinite search space to a finite one. This basically solves the problem because we can check the remaining finite number of candidates either by hand or by a computer.

Assume $(x, y)$ is a solution. Of course we have $3^y < x^3$. Also, for $x \geq 27$, we have $x^3 - (x-1)^3 > 2015$; therefore, we need to have $(x-1)^3 < 3^y < x^3$. This is equivalent to $\frac{3}{\log 3} \log (x-1) < y < \frac{3}{\log 3} \log (x)$. However, notice that $\frac{3}{\log 3} \log (x) - \frac{3}{\log 3} \log (x-1) < 1$ for $x \geq 4$, so there can be no integer between them.

This shows that there is no solution when $x \geq 27$.

Searching through the numbers with $x < 27$ and $y < 9$, we find that the only solution is $x = 14$ and $y = 6$.

Comment: How do you conclude $(x-1)^3 < 3^y < x^3$? I don't see how that follows from the previous statement.

Comment: @quarague Because $3^y \leq (x - 1)^3 \ \Rightarrow \ -(x - 1)^3 \leq -3^y \ \Rightarrow \ 2015 < x^3 - (x - 1)^3 \leq x^3 - 3^y = 2015$.

Comment: True, I missed that part. The second argument still doesn't hold, an interval can have size smaller than $1$ and still have an integer in it. Let $x=39$ and $y=10$ than you can check that $(x-1)^3 < 3^y < x^3$. In fact for any $y$ you can find an $x$ such that this relation is satisfied.

Comment: For example, the inequality
$
(x-1)^3 < 3^y < x^3
$
is satisfied for $x=39,\,y=10$, contrary to your claim that the inequality has no positive integer solutions with $x\ge 27$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I cannot delete my answer because it is accepted.